# program freeze running batch file

Tags: vb.net

I have a batch file being called within a program. When the batch file is called, the program seemed to freeze until it finished.

My Process:

```
Dim getUpdate As Process
getUpdate.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\UTIL\GETBTCH.BAT"
getUpdate.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
getUpdate.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
getUpdate.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\UTIL\"
getUpdate.Start()
```

I am looking for a way to if possible, call the batch file, preferably hide it but will run externally, thus, possibly not affecting the program to freeze or paused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps create a new project which does the batch updating, then call it with Process.start()

or, you can check out [the Background Worker](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/BackgroundWorkerDemo.htm)

Comment: also you might want to read on about it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx#Y0